# Generic Constraints with type of Number interface or String interface

Tags: typescript

I need to create a class with constraint on a generic type parameter.

The type should be one of 3 types:  the Number interface,  the String interface or Boolean interface.

Something like this:

```
type valueType = String | Number | Boolean;
class myClass<T extends valueType> {
    value!: Type<T>;
    getData() {
        //.....
        if (this.value == Number) {        }
    }
}
```

Note,   The T type will not allowed numbers or strings or Booleans , BUT The native number or string or Boolean ts interfaces, so that this code will be compiled successfully:

```
 let o1 = new myClass<Number>();
 let o2 = new myClass<String>();
```

but this:

```
 let o3 = new myClass<"str">();
```

or this:

```
 let o3 = new myClass<123>();
```

will fail.

Besides, I assume something basic in my code is bad, because I get an error in the line:

```
if (this.value == Number)
```

```
This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'Type<T>' and 'NumberConstructor' have no overlap
```

Comment: What’s the specific question you’re asking here? Is it that you want someone to write the class for you from scratch? Or tell you the myriad problems with the example code here? I’m not sure what `Type` is supposed to be, nor why you’d need to exclude subtypes in your constraint, nor why you want to use the interfaces for primitive wrapper objects instead of the primitive types themselves (e.g., I expect to see `number`, not `Number`, as a type here).  Could you [edit] to clarify and make sure any example code is a [mre]?